# Query for task start and end dates in Activiti

Tags: java, activiti, bpmn

I'm looking for a solution to query completed tasks in Activiti by filtering on the completion date. Because once they're finished completed task entries are being moved into the `act_hi_taskinst` table by the BPMN engine i would expected the required filters to be in the [`HistoricTaskInstanceQuery`](http://activiti.org/javadocs/org/activiti/engine/history/HistoricTaskInstanceQuery.html) class. However there's nothing like `startedAfter`/`startedBefore` and `finishedAfter`/`finishedBefore` methods like in the [`HistoricProcessInstanceQuery`](http://activiti.org/javadocs/org/activiti/engine/history/HistoricProcessInstanceQuery.html). The table has the `start_time_` and `end_time_` columns so there's no reason why this kind of query would be not possible.

Is there an other way to filter by these properties or currently the only way to get around this is to query the `act_hi_tasks` table directly bypassing the Activiti engine?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Activiti provides [Query API](http://activiti.org/userguide/index.html#queryAPI) so there is no need to query `act_hi_taskinst` directly.
You query may look like this one

```
NativeHistoricTaskInstanceQuery taskQuery = historyService.createNativeHistoricTaskInstanceQuery();
taskQuery.sql("SELECT * FROM "+ managementService.getTableName(HistoricTaskInstance.class)+" WHERE start_time_=#{startTime} AND end_time_=#{endTime}");
taskQuery.parameter("startTime", startTime).parameter("endTime", end_time);
List<HistoricTaskInstance> tasks = taskQuery.list();
```

Comment: Thank you. This looks ugly but it's still better to access table contents this way. If nothing better comes i'll accept this.