# Alfresco - display completed tasks on JSP page

Tags: jsp, alfresco, activiti

Can anybody give me a suggestion on how to display list of historicTaskInstances on JSP page? 
I wanted to get completed tasks between two dates and this question helped me to do that:
[Query for task start and end dates in Activiti](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16101151/query-for-task-start-and-end-dates-in-activiti) 
Now I need table with columns that represent parameters of this tasks, like *"assignee"* or *"completionDate"*. 
I'm a newbie in Alfresco and I would appreciate any advice or link where I can find something similar!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! May I refer you to this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using current versions of `aciviti` then you can solve your problem by following these approaches:

1 - JAVA API

```
historyService.createHistoricProcessInstanceQuery()
.finished()
.processDefinitionId("XXX")
.orderByProcessInstanceDuration().desc()
.listPage(0, 10);
```

2 - REST API

```
GET history/historic-process-instances
```

For more details you can follow : [activiti user guide](http://www.activiti.org/userguide)